# What does Bonus Points Remaining mean in league play?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

What does **Bonus Points Remaining : 1600** mean?

Comment: Please keep posts limited to a single question.  Move one of these questions to its own post.

Comment: Okey I will. Do you know the answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bonus points are extra XP that are awarded based on playing. [Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/669289-call-of-duty-black-ops-ii/66213823)

Comment: Will add more info later but thats the jest. On my mobile at the moment.